# create a new array, removing duplicates and setting state with React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have a MenuOptions component that I pass an options prop to. Options is a large array of objects. Each object has a nested array called 'services' inside services is an object with a key 'serviceType' which is the only value I want. I want to take all those values, push them into a new array and remove any duplicates if there are any, and then map through that new array and display each item in an 'option' html tag.

here is my createArray function:

```
    const createNewArray = () => {
        let optionsArr = []
        let uniqueArr;

        options.map((option) => {
            option.services.map((service) => optionsArr.push(service.serviceType))
        })
        uniqueArr = [...new Set(optionsArr)];
        return uniqueArr;
    }
```

uniqArr seems to be holding what I want but now I want to set this to a piece of global state. Trying something like this does not work. array seems to still be set as null

```
    const [array, setArray] = useState(null)

   useEffect(() => {
      setArray(createNewArray())
   }, [])
```

any solutions? Thanks

Comment: I have posted a solution please check it out if it is what you wanted

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not work" ?

Comment: Can you show a bit more context? What does MenuOptions definintion look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You should add your `array` state initial value as an empty array:

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([]);
```

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**2)** You can simplify the creating of a new array as:

```
const createNewArray = () => [
  ...new Set(options.flatMap((o) => o.services.map((obj) => obj.serviceType)))
];
```

**3)** set `array` state in `useEffect` as:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setArray(createNewArray());
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description is this your data?

```
const options = [{
  services: [
    {
      serviceType: 'serviceType',
    }
  ],
},{
  services: [
    {
      serviceType: 'serviceType',
    }
  ],
},{
  services: [
    {
      serviceType: 'serviceType',
    }
  ],
},
{
  services: [
    {
      serviceType: 'serviceType',
    }
  ],
}]
```

here is the solution

```
const uniq = (a) => [...new Set(a)];

const createNewArray = (array) => {
  const c = [...array]
  const newArray = []
  for (let i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    const e = c[i];
    for (let ii = 0; ii < e.length; ii++) {
      const ee = e[ii].serviceType;
      newArray.push(ee);
    }
  }
  const toReturn = uniq(newArray)
  return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Why not just simply, `fn = (a) => [...new Set(a)]`?

Comment: By the looks of it they have a working implementation, they're instead asking about how it isn't rendering

Comment: Oh, yeah you are right, this question needs more context

Answer (score 0):

If you want unique options, just pass the options in and set them to the state after you massage the data.

```js
const { useEffect, useMemo, useState } = React;

const unique = (arr) => [...new Set(arr)];

const uniqueOptions = (options) =>
  unique(options.flatMap(({ services }) =>
    services.map(({ serviceType }) => serviceType)));

const data = {
  options: [
    { services: [{ serviceType: "Home"  } , { serviceType: "About" }] },
    { services: [{ serviceType: "About" } , { serviceType: "Help"  }] },
    { services: [{ serviceType: "Help"  } , { serviceType: "Home"  }] },
  ],
};

const MenuOptions = (props) => {
  const { options } = props;

  const [opts, setOpts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => setOpts(uniqueOptions(options)), [options]);

  return useMemo(
    () => (
      <select>
        {opts.map((opt) => (
          <option key={opt} value={opt}>
            {opt}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    ),
    [opts]
  );
};

const App = ({ title }) =>
  useMemo(
    () => (
      <div>
        <h1>Services</h1>
        <form>
          <MenuOptions options={data.options} />
        </form>
      </div>
    ),
    []
  );

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react-app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-app"></div>
```